# how can I unsecure Xampp in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, xampp, phpmyadmin, localhost

when I access my IP in some other computer it requires username and password , I want no such type of security I want direct access to my xampp, phpmyadmin directory in any computer in same network.
I've attached some snapshots :
[image]

[image]

[image]